# curl append slist using custom function

Tags: c, curl

I try to append some strings using curl_slist_append(), this is part of my code, create_curl_slist function always returns SSXML_OK but in reality those strings are not appended.

```
    static SSXML create_curl_slist(struct curl_slist *chunk)
    {
        if ( (chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate") ) == NULL ) return SSXML_CURL_ERROR;
        if ( (chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8") ) == NULL ) return SSXML_CURL_ERROR;
        if ( (chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Content-Length: 306") ) == NULL ) return SSXML_CURL_ERROR;
        if ( (chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Host: test.test:8443") ) == NULL ) return SSXML_CURL_ERROR;
        if ( (chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Connection: Keep-Alive") ) == NULL ) return SSXML_CURL_ERROR;
        if ( (chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/12.0.1)") ) == NULL ) return SSXML_CURL_ERROR;
        if ( (chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Cookie: sap-usercontext=sap-client=100") ) == NULL ) return SSXML_CURL_ERROR;
    
        return SSXML_OK;
    }
    
    int some_func()
    {
        struct curl_slist *chunk = NULL;
        create_curl_slist(chunk);
//there is more here
        curl_slist_free_all(chunk);
    }
```

But when I do it inline like below, everything works fine

```
    int some_func()
    {
        struct curl_slist *chunk = NULL;
    
        if ( (chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate") ) == NULL ) return SSXML_CURL_ERROR;
        if ( (chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8") ) == NULL ) return SSXML_CURL_ERROR;
        if ( (chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Host: test.test:8443") ) == NULL ) return SSXML_CURL_ERROR;
        if ( (chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Connection: Keep-Alive") ) == NULL ) return SSXML_CURL_ERROR;
        if ( (chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/12.0.1)") ) == NULL ) return SSXML_CURL_ERROR;
        if ( (chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Cookie: sap-usercontext=sap-client=100") ) == NULL ) return SSXML_CURL_ERROR;
        if ( (chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Content-Length: 306") ) == NULL ) return SSXML_CURL_ERROR;
        curl_slist_free_all(chunk);
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `create_curl_slist(struct curl_slist *chunk)` updates its argument `chunk` and those updates are not visible to the caller. When execution returns to `some_func()`, its variable `chunk` is still `NULL`.

In the second example, `some_func()` updates its variable `chunk`.

Pass `chunk` by reference or return the updated `chunk`.